# Don't submit form when found restricted word in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to not submit form and send an alert popup when there is a word like this "[url]" found inside the textarea.

```js
function validateMyForm() {
  var txtchck = document.getElementById("checktext").value;
  if (txtchk.value.indexOf('[') > 0) {
    alert("validation failed false");
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="_form_element _field4 _full_width">
      <div class="_field-wrapper">
        <textarea name="field[4]" id="checktext" class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us something ..." style="height: 78px;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="_button-wrapper _full_width" style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="_form_13_submit" class="_submit" type="submit" style="width:60%; border-radius:4px !important;">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check url from regEx and `preventDefault` if found.

```js
function myFunction(e){
 let url= document.getElementById('url').value
 if(url.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi)){
   alert('contains url '+url);
   e.preventDefault();
 }else{
   alert('does not contains url');
 }
 
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction(event)">
  Enter Url string : <textarea  id="url">https://www.google.com/</textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there are errors on your script:

1. `txtchk` is not defined, you defined `txtchck`
2. `txtchck.value` will cause an error because `txtchck` is already the value of the input
3. `indexOf('[') > 0` would pass input value which begins with `[`

```js
function validateMyForm()
{
  var txtchck = document.getElementById("checktext").value;
  if(txtchck.indexOf('[') >= 0)
  { 
    alert("validation failed false");
    return false;
  }

  alert("validations passed");
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" id="_form_13_" class="_form _form_13 _inline-form  _dark" novalidate onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateMyForm();">
<div class="row">
    <div class="_form_element _field4 _full_width " >
        <label class="_form-label" style="color: #000 !important">
            Message
        </label>
        <div class="_field-wrapper">
            <textarea name="field[4]" id="checktext" class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us something ..." style="height: 78px;" ></textarea>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="_button-wrapper _full_width"  style="text-align:center;">
    <button id="_form_13_submit" class="_submit" type="submit" style="width:60%; border-radius:4px !important;">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```